# Host website one webfolder down

Tags: url, iis, directory

I want my site to be hosted like this:

```
mysite.com/en/default.aspx
mysite.com/en-gb/default.aspx
mysite.com/de-ch/default.aspx
```

Originally I just hosted the site in application folders in IIS for each culture I support and everything was fine.  I had a separate application in the root which forwarded the user to the appropriate culture.  This was all grand.

However, now we're going to host with Azure and I need to get my site to fit into one web role (for those not familiar with Azure, just think of it as me only being able to host the website once - so no application folders).  To this end, my site correctly collects the webfolder for the culture and sets the threading appropriately, all this is fine.  My problem is that now as far as IIS is concerned the page 'default.aspx' does not exist in the folder 'en-gb'.  That folder doesn't really exist.  I need to get my site to ignore that first webfolder when it considers what content to get.

It's an interesting one, I suspect my solution lies in URL rewriting.  Does anyone have any advice on this?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have found the answer.

It turns out that a web role is capable of much more.  I understood that it was a web site running under a virtual machine, but that virtual machine could be torn down and moved at any point.  However there is a facility to control what is going on in IIS on that virtual machine within your project.  By editing your ServiceDefinition.csdef file you can add virtual applications and virtual directories.  More details here:
http://www.dotnettwitter.com/2012/03/publishing-multiple-sites-sub-sites.html

I didn't need to use any fancy URL rewriting.  I now have several sites running under one web role.

Well... I will do once I figure out what is stopping my main site working under Azure, but this question is answered.